# Base de datos 1FN 2FN 3FN

Tags: base-de-datos

[image: Ayuda]

tengo un probmela con una base de datos e buscando informacion pero todo lo que se consigue es muy confuso, Cumple con las 3 primeras formas normales?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Parece que la 3FN sí que la cumples, tal vez demasiado, separando tanto las tablas: ¿un cliente puede tener más de un nombre? ¿Qué diferencia hay entre `venta`, `orden_compra` y `factura`?